# Silverstripe - Admin Login Form / Member Login Form

Tags: silverstripe

I am building a Silverstripe site that allow users to sign up to something. I have a few pages that in the CMS I set the page visibility to "Logged-in users" this is great but the default action is to redirect to /Security/Login. Is there a simple way of change the redirect for normal pages to goto etc /Account/Login and leave the default /Security/Login for CMS users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of another plugin, I used this bit of code

```
 public function onBeforeSecurityLogin()
 {
      $backUrl = $this->owner->getRequest()->getVar('BackURL');
      if (!strstr($backUrl, '/admin/')) {
          if (Controller::curr()->class != 'Account') {
                $link = 'account/login' . '?BackURL=' . urlencode($backUrl);
                return $this->owner->redirect($link);
          }
      }
  }
```

And I also extended the Security Class to create my own handler and form for logins

Answer (score 0):

You can set `?BackURL=/Account/Login` in your links, or in the `Session`.

Alternatively set the config variable, E.g:

```
Security:
  login_url: Account/Login
```

Comment: this would only set them for all users, not one link for one user type and a separate one for another